# want to update data in second fragment with SharePreferences but second Fragment is not updating

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am making a calculator app and want to update history in second fragment but not able to find a perfect solution for updating ListView in second fragment. I tried many solutions but none of them worked properly. **I'm using ViewPager to swipe between calculator and history fragments**. I tired bundle class but if I use bundle in OnCreat method of first Fragment(CalculatorFragment) with ViewPager it shows me blank screen after starting an App & if I use Bundle class in Equal Button it crashes app. here I am passing **id of viewPager as Container** of fragments.

I seen many answer perfectly working when they are using **Framelayout** for the container of Fragments but I want to keep swipe functionality of **ViewPager**, I tried many solutions but none of them worked properly with ViewPger, I added SharedPreferences to my code but it is not updating (not live) when I am using calculator. SharedPreferences seemed to work but they are not updating History when App is Running
And When I restart the app it shows me my last Calculation in History Fragment.

I passed SharedPreferences and fetch the string in onResume/onStart method's of second fragment(History fragment) but it only shows the history of last calculation when I closed my application

I am using Custom ArrayList to Store and display my History output in History Fragment.

I want to pass data(calculation to show history) to HistoryFragment whenever anyone clicks "=" button in application.
"=" button calls the equal method in calculator app.

**Example of what is happening**
[if I do this calculation in my calculator it does not update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgU0R.jpg)

[and in History it shows that last one from last when I closed application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9x4H.jpg)

**here's what I have done so far**

**it is the code of saving answer in CalculatorFragment.java(first fragment) using SharedPreferences**

I am also confused about which one to use .appy() or .commit()

```
public View onCreatView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);
         SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
         SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
         /*
                  other code
         */

public void Equals() {
        String calc = etCalc.getText().toString();
        if (calc.split("\\+").length == 2) {
            String[] calculation = calc.split("\\+");
            String Ans = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(calculation[0]) + 
                             Double.parseDouble(calculation[1]));
            etCalc.setText(Ans);
            tvCalc.setText(calc);
            mEditor.putString("key",calc+"="+Ans);
            mEditor.apply();
       }
}
```

**HistoryFragment.java**

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<HistoryList> historyLists;
    SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    String History = "";
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        History = mPreferences.getString("key", "");
        if (History.split("=").length == 2) {
            historyLists = new ArrayList<>();
            historyLists.add(new HistoryList(History.split("=")[0], History.split("=")[1]));
        }
        HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), historyLists);
        ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.history);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    pageAdapter pageAdapter;
    Button btnEqual;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "UseCompatLoadingForDrawables"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        //Get rid of ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.hide();
        pageAdapter = new pageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

      <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

comment if you need any other code of application.

Comment: make sure the equal() function is being called logging a value or show toast

Comment: @takieddine can you please explain in detail where to call equal method, I am a rookie in app dev, not exactly understood what & where you are telling me to implement this method

Comment: since you re calling editor.apply to save the data in sharedpreferences , now we need to first of all check if the equal() function is called , try toast message like this : Toast.make(this,"data saved",Toast.Length_Short).show()  , when you launch app and try to save the data it should show a toast , and tell me if it does

Comment: @takieddine I added Toast message in equal() method after data String is saved in SharedPreferences. and it is Showing me Toast message after code of  editor.apply();  runs.

Comment: Now in your history fragments in onResume() after getting the history value , try to log the string value  , Toast.make(this,"History is" + History ,Toast.Length_Short).show() and tell me if it shows the saved data or not

Comment: @takieddine it does not show any Toast message from onResume method in HistoryFragment, after equal() method is called first Toast message shows that "data saved" as you told me, but `Toast.makeText(getContext(),"History is: " + History ,Toast.Length_SHORT).show();` in onResume method of HistoryFragment is not appearing, HistoryFragment's onResume method only runs when I start application after colsing it , and it shows me last calculations history in Toast message.

Comment: try to get the sharedpreferences value in the onCreate() if it shows the value , then the problem is with onResume() method , onResume() is called when after the activity or fragment was paused , what are you trying to do with the onResume()

Comment: why are you using onResume()

Comment: you can simply copy the code on resume and call it onViewCreated() and it should work

Comment: @takieddine nope, not when app is running, when I do calculation, it does not get String from SharedPreferences in Historyfragment, it saves the data but HistoryFragment fetch the string only when I restart the application when I restart the app.

Comment: @takieddine comments are not loaded, when I commented, I'll try it onViewCreated()

Comment: hard luck I am not figuring out what is the issue here, thanks for your support

Comment: ok let me try to understand better your issue , so you have a calculator and when the user makes a calucation , it should be pushed into history fragment right , so the user knows what equations he already made ?

Comment: @takieddine yes that's what exactly I want to do, like if take google Calculator App for example, I don't know what they used for that, but if you swipe , you can find your last  10 or 20 equations and answers.

Comment: Okey you can have an activity that shows your calculator right , and then after the users get result , you pushed the data into local database , and i recommend you use Room db , you can read more about it on youtube or documentation , because with sharedpreferences the values will be updated and not added to the last one

Comment: So you can use room database to save values as soon as the user gets result and then in your history activity oncreate() , get the values from room database and show them in your adapter

Comment: no I am working with fragments, here I have one activity and 2 fragments. MainActivity contains viewpager and i am swiping through calculator and history fragments. thanks for reference. I'll check it out room db and try to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out solution for this problem. we can pass data through fragments using Shared ViewModel, no need to use SharedPreferences. we can set text to ViewModel and fetch it in second fragment, even when both fragments are in resumed condition(both are in resumed condition because here we are using simple ViewPager).

I am posting my code below for reference, how I updated data in second fragment.

Add this code in **MainActivity.java** file.
adding both fragments is necessary if you only add any one it will not have the slide effect of ViewPager.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.viewPager, new CalculatorFragment()).add(R.id.viewPager, new HistoryFragment()).commit();
```

Setting text to ViewModel in **CalculatorFragment.java** file.

```
public void Equals() {
        String calc = etCalc.getText().toString();
        if (calc.split("\\+").length == 2) {
            String[] calculation = calc.split("\\+");
            String Ans = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(calculation[0]) + 
                             Double.parseDouble(calculation[1]));
            etCalc.setText(Ans);
            viewModel.setText(Ans);
       }
//to send data to ViewModel
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

Make a class named **SharedViewModel.java**

```
package com.shashank.calculator;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<CharSequence> text = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public void setText(CharSequence input) {
        text.setValue(input);
    }
    public LiveData<CharSequence> getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and at last getting data from ViewModel in second **HistoryFragment.java**

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
 ArrayList<HistoryList> historyLists;
    HistoryAdapter adapter;
    SharedViewModel viewModel;
    String History;
    View rootView;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.history);
        historyLists = new ArrayList<>();
        return rootView;
    }
 public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // getting data from SharedViewModel and setting it to ListView
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), charSequence -> {
            History = String.valueOf(charSequence);
            adapter = new HistoryAdapter(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), historyLists);
            historyLists.add(0,History);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```